Handling Race Conditions in IOptionsMonitor<T> When T Depends on Other Options in .NET Core
I'm using IOptionsMonitor where T is dependent on other options in my service. There seems to be a race condition when using the OnChange event because the IOptions are initialized asynchronously on Reload, leading to T being initialized before the dependent options. This causes old values to appear in the OnChange event.
To demonstrate the issue let's have this sample repo:
public class FirstOptions
{
    public string FirstValue { get; set; }
}

public class SecondOptions
{
    public string SecondValue { get; set; }
}

internal class Worker : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IDisposable _disposable;
    private readonly string _filePath = "Config.ini";

    public Worker(IOptionsMonitor<SecondOptions> options)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Ctor: \"{options.CurrentValue.SecondValue}\"");
        _disposable = options.OnChange(OnOptionsChanged);
    }

    private void OnOptionsChanged(SecondOptions options, string? arg2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} OnChange: Second: {options.SecondValue}");
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            WriteFirstValue(_filePath, i.ToString());
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static void WriteFirstValue(string filePath, string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Property changed to " + value);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath,
            "[FirstSection]"
            + Environment.NewLine + $"FirstValue=\"{value}\"");
    }
}



internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
            .AddIniFile("config.ini", false, true)
            .Build();

        var provider = configurationRoot.Providers.OfType<IniConfigurationProvider>().First();

        IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            services.AddOptions<FirstOptions>().Bind(configurationRoot.GetSection("FirstSection"));
            services.AddOptions<SecondOptions>()
            .Bind(configurationRoot.GetSection("SecondSection"))
            .Configure<IOptionsMonitor<FirstOptions>>((secondOpt, firstOpt) => secondOpt.SecondValue = firstOpt.CurrentValue.FirstValue);
            //.Configure(secondOpt => secondOpt.SecondValue = configurationRoot.GetSection("FirstSection").GetValue<string>("FirstValue"));
        });

        IHost host = builder.Build();
        host.Run();
    }
}

The output shows a lag in updating SecondOptions values:
15:53:00.677 Property changed to 0
15:53:00.957 OnChange: Second: 0
15:53:01.222 OnChange: Second: 0
15:53:02.703 Property changed to 1
15:53:02.970 OnChange: Second: 0
15:53:03.222 OnChange: Second: 1
15:53:04.713 Property changed to 2
15:53:04.975 OnChange: Second: 1
15:53:05.228 OnChange: Second: 2
15:53:06.727 Property changed to 3
15:53:06.994 OnChange: Second: 2
15:53:07.259 OnChange: Second: 3

Using IConfigurationRoot directly solves the problem, but I'd prefer not to use it. According to ASP.NET documentation for 5.0, "Don't use IOptions or IOptionsMonitor in Startup.ConfigureServices. An inconsistent options state may exist due to the ordering of service registrations." I'm not sure if I'm facing the same issue. However, this comment is missing in the documentation for 6.0/8.0.
Is there an alternative way to fix this without using ConfigurationRoot?

where T is dependent on other options don't do that. T is supposed to be the deserialized configuration data, not a service that depends on others, or whose values are produced from other data.  IOptions isn't a notification or eventing mechanism, it's a way to provide strongly-typed data and up-to date configuration data into objects that match the data. It's not a data transformation service either

In other words, there's no race condition. The assumptions behind .Configure<IOptionsMonitor<FirstOptions>>((secondOpt, firstOpt) => secondOpt.SecondValue = firstOpt.CurrentValue.FirstValue); are wrong. There's no guarantee all settings will be updated at the same time. The values can easily come from different sources entirely, that raise changes at the same time. If you want stable data use IOptionsSnapshot, preferably in a scope. By using Monitor you asked for the current data, no matter what.

@PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for shedding some light on this issue. If it's advisable to avoid the IOptions dependency, what would be the best alternative? I cannot use IOptionsSnapshot, as it's a singleton service that needs to respond to changes. Or did you mean something different?
Currently, my setup involves a config.ini file with a general section that I use in various options. For example, UserSessionOptions is composed of parts of the general section combined with specific UserSessionOptions.
Maybe my whole architecture is wrong and it is not the way how IOptions should be used. :/
